# Show current URL in Vimperator status line

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I used to be able to show the current page's URL in the Vimperator status line while in :open mode by hitting the up arrow (i.e., without yanking it to the clipboard), but that is no longer working (it just displays the last URL in history, not the current URL). Does anyone know what I might have changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the problem that happened with Firefox 49 where Vimperator's smart completions stopped working.

https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/590

What changed? It looks like the name of the autocomplete search provider in Firefox changed from `history` to `unifiedcomplete`.

The  work around suggested worked fine for me while waiting for a fix - add the following to `~/.vimperatorrc` file:

```
js services.services.autoCompleteSearch.class_="@mozilla.org/autocomplete/search;1?name=unifiedcomplete"
```